# Data Storage Solutions - CodeNameOne || Java || Data

Tags: java, codenameone, data-storage

Mobile App Scenario:

This application will be used as a UI to send and retrieve client records (name, contact info. etc)

My Level:

I am new to CodeNameOne and have only created three applications as part of previous university projects (no data storage used). I have experience using PHP and connecting a form to a database with SQL.

What I am trying to achieve:

I am looking for a solution to my problem and to store my client data and then get back the data using my already designed UI with CodeNameOne.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a powerful tool in Codename One to storage data in local file : **Storage**.
Here's an example :

```
MyObject ob1 = new MyObject();
MySecondObject ob2 = new MySecondObject();

//Here we write locally the data object
Storage.getInstance().writeObject("myObject1", ob1);
Storage.getInstance().writeObject("myObject2", ob2);

//Here we read it to get it back (Caution : We ask storage if the object exist) 
MyObject ob1Back = Storage.getInstance().exists("myObject1")?(MyObject) Storage.getInstance().readObject("myObject1"):new MyObject();
MySecondObject ob2Back = Storage.getInstance().exists("MySecondObject")?(MySecondObject) Storage.getInstance().readObject("MyObject2"):new MySecondObject();
```

Comment: I'd also add a reference to the relevant section in the developer guide: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html

Comment: Thank you Tim! This is exactly what I was wanting.